# How to fix the starter encryption menu after installing a new driver?

Tags: linux-mint

I'm running Linux Mint 17.3 Cinnamon with Nvidia-352 (recommended). After I changed from Xserver-xorg* (open source) my Linux Mint start is weird. I've encrypted my system. Before I changed to the recommended driver, I was shown a window where I could enter my passphrase. Now I just get an empty black page, where I blindly can enter my passphrase.

Sometimes there is some text like * failed. But it's too fast to read it. But I always get locked in anyway.